# How to create user and database with docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning docker and basically i am trying to create a mysql docker image with database and a user.

I went through the mysql docker documentation and it states that:

```
When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

So i have created the following dockerFile:

```
    FROM mysql/mysql-server:8.0.22 
    
    ENV TZ Asia/Muscat
    
    COPY mysql-init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The mysql-init.sh is defined as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

echo "Creating database..."

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$MYSQL_USER" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER test PASSWORD '$DB_TEST_PWD';
    CREATE DATABASE test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO test;
EOSQL
```

When i built the image the log is shown below as image is created successfully:

[image]

Then I have created a docker-compose file to start the mysql  image as follows:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
 db:
    image: mysqlcustom
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      DB_TEST_PWD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

But i get the following error while executing docker-compose up:

```
PS D:\Projects\mysql\dockerCompose> docker-compose up
Creating dockercompose_db_1 ... done
Attaching to dockercompose_db_1
db_1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.22-1.1.18
db_1  | [Entrypoint] Initializing database
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:44.321419Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) initializing of server in progress as process 20
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:44.325833Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:45.026268Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:46.309559Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db_1  | [Entrypoint] Database initialized
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.034016Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 63
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.047504Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.203569Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.294241Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.388271Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.388422Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db_1  | 2021-01-06T19:33:50.405225Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1  |
db_1  | [Entrypoint] running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sh
db_1  | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong please?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of large image files to your question as the output of your container.  I'd expect the container to write out text-format logs; can you replace the images with the actual text output of the containers?

Comment: The two immediate things that jump out at me looking at this are the `bash` shebang line (the database may not have this shell), and that you're using the PostgreSQL `psql` client in an otherwise MySQL environment.  The bottom pixels of the last image suggest the script file has DOS line endings, which could also be a problem.  If you just want to create a database and user, the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has standard environment variables to set that up automatically.

Comment: thanks a lot  for the response, I went through docker hub mysql image,do you mean the environment variable can be added in the mysql-init.sh to create user and db?

Comment: Since the `docker-compose.yml` file declares `MYSQL_USER: user` and `MYSQL_DATABASE: test`, that user and database get created for you; you don't need that script.